# linux filter php result by word and write in file

Tags: linux, sh

I have a php file that only echo:

```
$ php exam.php
a
b
a
b
.... (always the same again and again)
```

And I want to put in a file only 'a':

```
$ php exam.php | grep "a" > res.txt
I tried
$ php exam.php | grep "a" >> res.txt
$ php exam.php | xargs -0 grep "a" > res.txt
$ php exam.php |& grep "a" > res.txt
$ php exam.php | grep a > res.txt
```

but nothing. What i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RES=$(php exam.php) && for VALUE in $RES; do echo $VALUE; done | grep -e "a"
```

I think it could be better, but for the moment.

The problem was that the response of the php was an array (I think so).

`RES=$(php exam.php)` execute the php and store the result in RES

`&&` to execute later if all works

`for...` to go through each value

`grep...` to get only the result wanted